# Uncaught TypeError: TextField is not a constructor jspdf

Tags: pdf-generation, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Getting this error when i am trying to integrate the input fields inside PDF. Its working in jspdf examples i.e http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master

You have to select the AcroForms from choose example. But then i try to integrate it its not working through error on console i.e **Uncaught TypeError: TextField is not a constructor**

Below are my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jsPDF - AcroForm</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            Test PDF <button onclick="generate()">GENERATE PDF </button>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
        <!-- Scripts down here -->
        <script   src="http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/examples/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js" ></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function generate()
           {
            console.log('Inside generate');
            const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
            var TextField = jsPDF.AcroForm; 
            doc.text("TextField:", 10, 145);
            var textField = new TextField();
            textField.Rect = [50, 140, 30, 10];
            textField.multiline = true;
            textField.value =
              "The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse The quick brown fox ate the lazy mouse"; //
            textField.fieldName = "TestTextBox";
            doc.addField(textField);
            
             doc.save('test.pdf');   
            /* global jsPDF */
           }
        </script>
        <!-- Code editor -->

        <script src="http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/examples/js/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <!-- Scripts in development mode -->
        <script src="http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/examples/js/pdfobject.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/examples/js/editor.js" ></script>
        <script src="acroform.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Calling the 'AcroFormTextField' constructor on the doc object worked for me:

```
var textField = new doc.AcroFormTextField();
```

Comment: I try but does not worked for me showing error message in console i.e jsPDF PubSub Error scope.internal.newObjectDeferred is not a function TypeError: scope.internal.newObjectDeferred is not a function

Answer (score 0):

After spending few hours i found the solution you guys can directly copy below and run it on browsers. text fields for jspdf working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jsPDF - Input fields</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
</head>

    <body onload="generate()">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>ON PAGE LOAD pdf download.</h1>
        </div> <!-- /container -->


        <!-- Scripts down here -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" rel="preload"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.2.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           var jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF; // on page load initate object
           
           function generate()
           {
            console.log('Inside generate');
            const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
            var TextField = jsPDF.AcroForm; 
            doc.text("TextField:", 10, 145);
            var textField = new doc.AcroFormTextField();
            textField.Rect = [50, 140, 30, 10];
            textField.multiline = false;
            textField.value =
              "Test Values"; //
            textField.fieldName = "TestTextBox";
            doc.addField(textField);
            
             doc.save('test.pdf');   
            /* global jsPDF */
           }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```